# Infragistics Silverlight XamGrid with different layouts in hierarchy

Tags: silverlight, infragistics

How can I create a `XamGrid` with a ColumnLayout that looks like,

| Name |

John

(+/-)

```
   | First Name | Last Name | Address |
```

Mary

(+/-)

```
| Height | Weight |
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description it appears that you would like to have a hierarchical grid where you would expand out different details for different rows.  The XamGrid does allow sibling ColumnLayouts in a nested layout and there is an example of this in the help topic for Defining Hierarchical Layouts:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/Current/CLR4.0?page=xamGrid_Defining_Hierarchical_Layouts.html